# UITabBar moving selected image

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have two UITableViewControllers that needed to be shown in "swipable tabs". That means you can swipe left / right from one to another. I found a lot of similar questions and answers, but couldn't connect them together to produce a solution that would fit my needs.
The problem is that I need also a "selected image", that shows which tab is selected. This image should move (follow your finger) when you swipe to change tab. I found a project on git that solves my problem, the only thing is that it uses navigation controller instead of tab controller so I don't know how to change that. 
Anyone already worked on a thing like this?

Example
https://github.com/cwRichardKim/RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers

Answer (score 0):

You need to set swipe gesture recognizers for these actions.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *returnToMainScreenSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector( returnToMainScreen:)];
    returnToMainScreenSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;


    [self.view addGestureRecognizer: returnToMainScreenSwipe];
```

And also selector

```
- (void)returnToMainScreen:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex: MIDDLE_TAB];
}
```

Comment: with swipe gestures, screen doesn't follow finger.